# Dynamic datatable take Reverse order in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application, I have created

```
 DataTable dt= new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("Month");
```

and made fill the column name "Month" with date as

```
Month(Column name)
oct-2014   
July-2016   
Aug-2016
```

and made fill my dynamic table

Now,  i want this dynamic table data to be Reverse order

```
for eg:

    Month(Column name)
      Aug-2016
      July-2016        
      oct-2014
```

like this i need to display dynamic data table is first row is last and last row is first.

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to sort based on this particular column ? Or you want to inverse the order of data in entire data table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
  DataTable reversedDt = dt.Clone();
  for (var row = dt.Rows.Count - 1; row >= 0; row--)
         reversedDt .ImportRow(dt.Rows[row]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Vicky you helped me

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the ordered table.

e.g.

```
var orderedRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable().Reverse()
                          select row;
dataGridView1.DataSource = orderedRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone's future reference.

I found if you clone the original table then just use a `For` loop but read from the bottom row up, that is the easiest way.

Also in VB but can easily be converted.

```vb
Dim newDataTable = dt.Clone()
For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    newDataTable.ImportRow(dt.Rows((dt.Rows.Count - 1) - i))
Next
```