# How to Take Dynamic datatable last row is in first row order like that all rows in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created,

```
 DataTable date= new DataTable();
 date.Columns.Add("datenmoth");
```

and made fill the column name "Month" with date as

```
Month(Column name)
05-oct-2014
06-Nov-2014
02-Dec-2014
02-jan-2015
01-feb-2015
20-mar-2015
```

and made fill my dynamic table

Now, i want this dynamic table data to be Reverse order

i need result in: based on month and year taking reverse order

```
 Month(Column name)
20-mar-2015
01-feb-2015
02-jan-2015
02-Dec-2014
06-Nov-2014
05-oct-2014
```

Thank you.

Comment: It will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743779/dynamic-datatable-take-reverse-order-in-asp-net/39744683#39744683

Comment: hi vicky i saw your code your code it's helpful but for reverse order but i need that reverse order and one year of data only that means for eg: aug-2016 to sept-2015 can you tell me this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't fill this table with strings but with `DateTimes`. If you use string as column-type you always have to convert it to a `DateTime`. Like here:

```
var dateInReversedOrder = date.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderByDescending(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("datenmoth")))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

That works but is inefficient and prone to localization issues (in future).

Sample data and (desired) result after sorting in descending order:

```
DataTable date = new DataTable();
date.Columns.Add("datenmoth");
date.Rows.Add("05-oct-2014");
date.Rows.Add("20-mar-2015");
```

[image]